# Usage of articles before adjectives

Tags: articles

Most of the time I have heard people say "Rahul is an honest person."

Which one is correct and why?

> He is an honest person.
>   He is honest person.
>
> She is an honest woman.
>   She is honest woman.

Comment: "Honest person" is a noun phrase, with the singular noun "person" as head. The NP normally requires a determiner before any modifiers.

Comment: Hemraj, yes, you need "an". English requires: a/an, the or plural. A simple rule: She is an honest woman; They are honest women. She is the honest woman I saw in the street. Just to help you remember the rule.

Answer (score 1):

*Person* and *woman* are count nouns, so they cannot occur in the singular without an article (except in a few special contexts). This is true whether or not they are preceded by an adjective.

So it must be ***an** honest person/woman*.

Answer (score 0):

He(Noun) is(Auxiliary Verb/ Main Verb) an(determiner) honest (adjective) person (noun).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but please clear me "an" is a take right  place in this sentence ?

Comment: yes the first one goes right because it is an attribution adjective

Answer (score 0):

You can say it in two different ways:

1. He is an honest person.
2. He is honest.

Answer (score 0):

She is an honest person.
He is an honest person.

The choice between *an* or *a* depends on the nearest phoneme in the the grammatical construction. It is  a word *honest* which is pronounced with the vowel sound [o short]. It makes necessary to use *an* as an indefinite article in such a collocation.

The grammatical construction of the sentence *She is an honest woman* is **Subject+linking verb be+attributive Adjective+Noun phrase**. Or, it is **Subject+Predicate+Subject complement** if we denote the sentence with the grammatical functions of its constituents.

The function of the **Subject Complement** in such construction is the description of the category which the **Subject** belongs to. Because the **Subject** is a concrete person denoted with the pronoun *she*, we should use an undefined set of persons having some specified feature for the **Subject Complement**. This meaning is conveyed by the noun phrase in which the indefinite article is in the initial attributive position.